# How can I have an optional one-to-one relationship in GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-one, grails-domain-class

I have 2 objects, `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`.

When `ObjectA` gets created, `ObjectB` doesn't (and *can't*, due to not having the data yet) exist yet.

Once `ObjectB` is created, it needs to have a corresponding `ObjectA` attached to it *if an appropriate one exists*. If there isn't an appropriate `ObjectA`, then the new `ObjectB` simply isn't connected to one.

So, all `ObjectA` instances will *eventually* be attached to an `ObjectB`, but not all `ObjectB` instances will have an `ObjectA`.

Essentially, I'm looking for GORM to build database tables like this:

```
ObjectA
- Id (NotNull, unique)
- ObjectB_Id[FK: ObjectB.Id] (unique)

ObjectB
- Id (NotNull, unique)
```

**How can I put together the GORM domain classes to do this?**

I've tried just about every combination of `hasOne`, `belongsTo`, raw properties, `nullable: true` and `unique: true` constraints I can think of, but I *must* be missing one. This doesn't seem like it's a particularly *odd* scenario, so there *must* be some way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is often the case, putting my thoughts together into a question lead me to the solution:

```
Class ObjectA {
    ObjectB objectB

    static constraints = {
        objectB nullable: true, unique: true
    }
}

Class ObjectB {
    static belongsTo = [objectA: ObjectA]

    static constraints = {
        objectA nullable: true
    }
}
```

The only catch with this that I can't seem to get around is that it's possible to set `ObjectB.objectA` to an `ObjectA` that is already associated with an `ObjectB`. When saving the new association, GORM just doesn't save the association. No errors are thrown, and pulling the new `ObjectB` out of the database leaves it's `objectA` property unset.

Adding `unique: true` to the `objectA` constraints in the `ObjectB` class doesn't help either. Instead of silently failing, an error is thrown indicating that the uniqueness check is failing due to an un-set parameter.